# Can i pass DateTime parameters in ui-router?

Tags: angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider
    .state('messagelogs', {
        controller: 'Messages',
        url:'/messageLogs/{pageIndex:int}/{itemsPerPage:int}/{text:string}/{fromDate:date}
})
```

> Will ui-router recognize :date?

Comment: yes,and it's not working...it only works if i put :fromDate

Comment: @Jakuje i want to know why can't i put :date for a datetime parameter.

Comment: No, you can't do that. You can pass it as a string and then parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own type. So, when you say $stateParams.someDate property you will always get instance of Date.
Here is some example, you can improve it

```
(function (angular, Date) {
    angular.module('some-module')
        .config(addCustomUrlParamType);

    addCustomUrlParamType.$inject = ['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider'];

    function addCustomUrlParamType($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
            $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('myDate', {
                name: 'myDate',
                decode: function (myDateValue) {
                    var timestamp;

                    if(angular.isDate(myDateValue)) {
                        return myDateValue;
                    }

                    timestamp = Date.parse(myDateValue);

                    if(!isNan(timestamp)) {
                        return new Date(timestamp);
                    }
                },

                /** 
                 * @description
                 * Detects whether a value is of a particular type. Accepts a native (decoded) value and determines whether 
                 * it matches the current Type object.
                 */
                is: function (myDateValue) {
                    return angular.isDefined(myDateValue) && this.decode(myDateValue) === myDateValue;
                }
            })
    }

}(this.angular, this.Date));
```

so, now you can say something like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('messagelogs', {
        controller: 'Messages',
        url:'/messageLogs/{pageIndex:int}/{itemsPerPage:int}/{text:string}/{fromDate:myDate}
});
```

and when you want to pass date, you can say:

```
$state.go('messagelogs', {fromDate: (new Date()).toISOString()})
```

or if you provide encode function that creates string from Date:

```
$state.go('messagelogs', {fromDate: new Date()})
```

You can find more on:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:Type